# Set <title> attribute of homepage in Jekyll Minima theme

Tags: jekyll

Running the following three shell commands creates a Jekyll site with the default Minima theme and serves it to the browser:

```bash
jekyll new test_blog
cd test_blog/
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

By default, the HTML `<title>` element of the rendered index page includes both the blog title and the description, so that it appears as follows:

[image]

**I would like to remove the description and display the only the title.** Normally, the way you do this is by copying the default `_includes/head.html` to your local site directory and modifying the `<title>` element accordingly. But the default `_includes/head.html` includes no `<title>` element to speak of:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  {%- seo -%}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/main.css" | relative_url }}">
  {%- feed_meta -%}
  {%- if jekyll.environment == 'production' and site.google_analytics -%}
    {%- include google-analytics.html -%}
  {%- endif -%}
</head>
```

... nor do any of the other files in the basic Minima template, as far as I can tell by `grep`. I tried adding a line `<title>My Literal Title</title>` in `_includes/head.html` as well, but it seems to be get overwritten by something else, because it has no effect on the displayed title.

**How can I change the formatting of the homepage title in the Jekyll Minima template?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If modifying `_includes/head.html` to add a title element, the title will not change if the new title element is added below the `{%- seo -%}` line. Add it above that line, and the `|` and description will be removed.

I tested this on a fresh install of Jekyll and created the `_includes/head.html` in the directory.

Comment: Neither of these solutions work. The first one produces the title `Title in index | Blog title` where `Blog title` is the `title:` given in `_config.yml`. It also registers the index itself as a "page," creating a redundant link to it in the header navigation. The second produces the title `Title in config | Write an awesome description ...` as described in my post. I want to remove the vertibar `|` and everything after it.

Comment: Your are right. I missed the part where you wanted the `|` and description removed. I noticed a strange behaviour when modifying `_includes/head.html`. I edited my answer to better respond to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the behavior I wanted using `<title>{%- if page.title -%}{{page.title}} | {{site.title}}{%- else -%}{{site.title}}{%- endif -%}</title>`. I think the buggy behavior has to do with the order of the parsers and whether `|` gets interpreted as a part of the string or as a switch, since in other contexts `{{ a | b}}` interpolates `a` if it is defined and `b` if not.

Comment: A better idea would be to replace `{% seo %}` with `{% seo title=false %}`, as per the [Jekyll docs](https://jekyll.github.io/jekyll-seo-tag/advanced-usage/).